# asp.net mvc _ViewStart DI Hooks

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Is there any way I can inject / build up dependencies on a _ViewStart class without calling my service locator directly?

Thanks
Ben

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Get an instance of a settings object within _viewstart in order to set the layout page

Comment: If setting the layout page is all you need to do, you can just do this in your controller using one of the View() overloads: `ViewResult View(string viewName, string masterName)` and `ViewResult View(string viewName, string masterName, object model)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand how you can inject your settings when the _ViewStart class (System.Web.Mvc.ViewStartPage) doesn't have a property to hold them.

Assuming you're trying to avoid fetching your settings in _ViewStart, a possible solution would be to create a custom ViewStartPage class that has a property for your settings, and call the service locator from within there:

```
/* CustomViewStart.cs */
public class CustomViewStart : System.Web.Mvc.ViewStartPage
{
    public ISettings Settings { get; set; }

    public CustomViewStart()
    {
        // Call service locator here
        this.Settings = blah
    }
}
```

To use this, you need to set the base class in your _ViewStart:

```
@* _ViewStart.cshtml *@
@inherits MyTestApp.CustomViewStart
```

There doesn't seem to be (or certainly I can't find) a way to set the base class for this in Web.config like you can with basePageType :(

Comment: Tried that and got a weird error that it needs to derive from either WebViewPage or ViewStartPage which it does.